# The kind of safe a large company uses for important documents

Tags: security, confidentiality

Wondering what a larger company with resources uses to store important potentially confidential documents. Or what is recommended as best practices if most companies don't typically adhere to them. Basically, if you have signed some contract like the Apple/Sprint $2B contract, I would imagine that that is *not* entirely stored in the cloud, and there is some portion of documents that are physically printed out and signed, and then stored somewhere. Wondering how they are safely stored.

What I would imagine is, short of putting them into something like a hardcore bank vault, is simply putting them into a safe inside of a locked room. I am wondering what kind of key would be best for the door, because metal keys seem to be easily pickable. So it seems that they would have a digital combination lock or a swipey magnetic lock, though I don't know how secure that is. Then the safe would have the same sort of lock. Wondering if this is typically what is done, or if they are stored in less of a hardcore way, or more of a hardcore way. For example, Coca Cola's trade secret for their mixture, maybe that is highly protected, or yeah, the Sprint/Apple contract, or other things of that nature.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about purchasing hardware not navigating the office.

Comment: This seems like it was intended for a forum about the physical workplace, not the abstract workplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some secure a whole room, steel door, combination lock, much like a vault. Other use a big safe and bolt it into the floor and wall. Too big and heavy to be easily carried away by a few men and they'd need a truck.

Most safes are not picked like in movies. The whole safe is taken and cut open later.

The lock isn't that important, all reputable safe makers don't put in locks that are easy to open. Big safes I have seen opened were all cut into. Failed attempts I have seen did some damage to locks and doors but didn't actually get in and they used drills and what must have been big 6 foot crowbars in the attempts to do the damage they did.